# resources are not found on IIS6

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have IIS6, and aspx are working, but all the JS, CSS, images are declared as NOT FOUND.
This is initial installation of the IIS and project as virtual directory.

Any guesses what it can be? I made the virt directory PUBLIC in case permissions are the issue

thanks

Comment: Show us the code.. may be you are using wrong paths or File path in your url...

Comment: I have resources in the right path... It is working in other computers (they dont have initial setup though)

Comment: you mean its not working for your own localhost but working perfect on remote computer.?

Comment: It is working locally too but in other computers.

Comment: without code or sample .. i am just playing a guessing game. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I ran aspnet_regiis -i again.